# Huffman's Algortihm Probability Distributions

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I am currently studying a bit of coding and information theory. I just learned Huffman's algorithm. I was solving some problems and came up with this one:

*Given a code $C=\{0,10,110,111\}$ as a result of Huffman's algorithm construction, what are its probability distributions $P=\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$?*

My approach is to think of $C$ as a binary tree and analyze it from the bottom up using Huffman's algorithm. $110$ and $111$ have the same ascendant vertex. So,
$$p_4\leq p_1,p_2\text{ and }p_3\leq p_1,p_2.$$
Also,
$$p_2\leq p_1\text{ and }p_3+p_4\leq p_1.$$
My **question(s)** is(are): Is $p_3,p_4\leq p_2\leq p_1$ and $p_3+p_4\leq p_1$ enough of an answer? Is this correct? Is there more to explore? In advance, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're approach and result are both correct.

Edit: In general, if two symbols have Huffman codeword lengths $\ell_i$ and $\ell_j$, then

$$ \ell_i > \ell_j \implies p_i \le p_j$$
$$ \ell_i > \ell_j +1 \implies p_i < p_j$$

while $ \ell_i  = \ell_j $ does not imply anything.

This also applies to grouped symbols. That is, if two codewors are equal except for the last bit, so that $\ell_j =  \ell_k$, then you can combine them into a new pseudo-symbol $m$ with $\ell_m =\ell_j-1$ and $p_m=p_j+p_k$, and the same relationships above apply.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1560795)

Comment: Dear bot: I understand you, but this is the answer to the question.

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for the answer! If our code was $C=\{00,01,10,11\}$, then it could be any distribution, right? Huffman's algorithm doesn't tell us anything. What do you think?

Comment: No, it could not be any distribution. There is no inequality for the isolated values ($p_i- p_j$ can be negative, positive or zero), but, for example, you know that $p_1 + p_2 \ge p_3$

Comment: Yes, of course. If $10$ and $11$ are chosen first, then I may say $p_3+p_4\geq p_1,p_2$. Similarly if $00$ and $01$ are chosen first.

Comment: @leonbloy are you also familiar with syndrome decoding. If so, could I ask you to check my other question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062144/syndrome-decoding-coset-leader